# Seeking explanation for this for loop pair

Tags: c, for-loop

I've been experimenting with numerical output patterns with for loops and I'm having trouble understanding exactly what this piece of code is doing. Can someone explain line by line on why this displays the output that it does? Any help is always appreciated..

```
 int main() {

     int x, y; 
     for(x = 10; x >= 1; x--)
     {
         for(y = 1; y < x; y++)    
         {
             printf("%d", y);
         }
         printf("\n");
     }

     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Is this for homework?  Edit: Also, those aren't `while` loops...

Comment: There is almost nothing to explain. This is what loops do. You should try to understand this by yourself.

Comment: No, it's not homework. If that were the case the code wouldn't have been completed. I'm actually curious as to how this works so I can better understand the language of C.

Comment: homework often consists of describing existing code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two loops, one insider the other.

The outer loop (`x`) counts from 10 down to 1 inclusive:

```
for(x = 10; x >= 1; x--)
```

The inner loop (`y`) counts from 1 up to `x - 1` inclusive. It will iterate over this range for every single value that `x` takes in the outer loop.

```
for(y = 1; y < x; y++)
```

So it will work out like this:

- In the beginning, `x == 10`, and `y` will take the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. These numbers will be printed one after the other.
- Then (after the inner loop finishes) `x` will become 9 and therefore for the next iteration, `y` will print the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.
- ...
- On the previous to last iteration `x` will become 2 and `y` will only print the value `1`.
- Finally, on the last iteration `x` will be `1` and the inner loop will not run at all (there will be no numbers greater than 1 but less than `x`). So the very last line will be blank.

Answer (score 2):

On the outer loop, you're setting `x` with descending values down till `x >= 1`.  In other words, you're looping across values of `x` for `10, 9, ..., 1`.

```
 for(x = 10; x >= 1; x--)
 {
```

In the inner loop, you're going through the values of `y=1` until `y<x`.

So, when `x=10`, `y=1,2, ...9`.

When `x=9`, `y=1,2, ...8`.

And so on.

```
     for(y = 1; y < x; y++)    
     {
```

Within the inner loop, you're printing out the values of `y`.

```
         printf("%d", y);
     }
```

At the end of each inner loop, you're printing a line break.

```
     printf("\n");
 }
```

Effectively, you're printing out a sting of `y` values in a single line for each value of `x`. So, with `x` going from `10` to `1`, you'd expect an output as such:

```
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Comment: `x >= 1`. (10, 9, ..., **1**)

Answer (score 0):

```
 int main() {

 int x, y; 
 for(x = 10; x >= 1; x--)
 {
   // this for loop will run 10 times, with x values: 10 9 8 ... 2 1
   for(y = 1; y < x; y++)    
   {
     // will print 1234 ... up to one less than the current value of x
     printf("%d", y);
   }
   printf("\n");
 }

 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

Expect output

```
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Answer (score 0):

`int main() {}` this is the name of the method

`int x, y;` this is declaring two integers with no values stored in them (e.g. x=no number & y = no number).

`for(x = 10; x >= 1; x--)`  this sets x = 10 then executes the code within the given block multiple times decrementing x by 1 through each pass up until it reaches 1 which then stops the loop.

`for(y = 1; y < x; y++)`  this sets y = 1 then executes the code within the given block multiple times increasing y by 1 through each pass up until it reaches a value below x.

`printf("%d", y);`  this prints the value of y.
 `printf("\n");`    this starts a new line
 `system("pause");` this pauses the system
 `return 0;` this returns 0 thus ending the program

Answer (score 0):

This is just looping through y from 1 to "1 less than x". Within an outer loop where x is decreasing from 10 down to 1.

```
int x, y;  //Declare 2 integers x and y.

for(x = 10; x >= 1; x--)      //Loop through values of x starting with 10 then decrease by 1 until x = 1. Each time do the following:
{          
    for(y = 1; y < x; y++)  //Loop through values for y starting at 1 and going to 1 less than the x from the line above. Each time do the following:            
    {
        printf("%d", y);  // Print the value of y as a decimal integer               
    }   
    printf("\n");      //Print a carriage return. i.e. start a new line after this.
}

system("pause");  //Wait so you can see the output until you type a key.

return 0; //When this program is run it will return a value of 0 to whereever it was called from.
```

You should see the following output.

```
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```